# Order a recipe queryset by replies number using django-disqus

Tags: python, django, disqus

I have a `recipe` model:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_("Recipe Title"), max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('user'))
...
```

I need create a view for most commented recipes, i'm using `django-disqus` for handling recipe's comments, but i don't know how can i order the queryset by the recipe's comment number.

```
class PopRecipeListView(GlobalQueryMixin, ListView):
    model = Recipe
    context_object_name = "recipe_list"
    template_name = 'recipe/recipe_top_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(PopRecipeListView, self).get_queryset()

        if qs:
            qs = qs.extra(
                select={
                    'comments': # get comment numbers
                }
            ).filter(shared=True).order_by('-rate')[:20]

        return qs
```

I found this in documentation: https://disqus.com/api/docs/forums/listThreads/
I can get a `json` file with the site and forum id and iterate over them for get the properly key, but i think it is not easy.

Looking more deep i can get the `json` file using some like this:
`var url = "https://disqus.com/api/3.0/forums/listThreads.json?api_key=" + api_key + "&forum=" + forum; //+ "&limit=100";`, but i am not sure about it.

Ok, i have the next function for get that parameters:

```
def get_comments_by_site():
    api_key = settings.DISQUS_API_KEY
    forum = settings.DISQUS_WEBSITE_SHORTNAME

    url = 'https://disqus.com/api/3.0/forums/listThreads.json?api_key={0}&forum={1}&limit=100'.format(api_key, forum)

    raw = requests.get(url)
    dict = json.loads(raw)

    values = {}

    for thread in dict['response']:
        item = {thread['slug']: thread['posts']}
        values.update(item)

    return values


def get_comments_number(slug):
    return values[slug]
```

I made two different functions because i want that `View` get all value at once, and after, in the `query` call the secong function for get the values from the obtained dictionary.

I created a `mixin` to integrate the two functions:

```
class DisqusCommentsNumber(object):
    values = {}

    def get_comments_by_site(self):
        api_key = settings.DISQUS_API_KEY
        forum = settings.DISQUS_WEBSITE_SHORTNAME

        url = 'https://disqus.com/api/3.0/forums/listThreads.json?api_key={0}&forum={1}&limit=100'.format(api_key,
                                                                                                          forum)

        raw = requests.get(url)
        dict = json.loads(raw)

        for thread in dict['response']:
            item = {thread['slug']: thread['posts']}
            self.values.update(item)

        return self.values

    def get_comments_number(self, slug):
        return self.values[slug]
```

I'm using `annotate` here:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(PopRecipeListView, self).get_queryset()

    if qs:
        qs = qs.annotate(num_comments=get_comments_number('slug')).filter(shared=True).order_by('-num_comments')

    return qs
```

I replaced `annotate` by `extra` and:

def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(PopRecipeListView, self).get_queryset()

```
if qs:
    qs = qs.extra(
        select={
            'num_comments': '{0}'.format(
                self.get_comments_number(Recipe.slug)
            )
        }
    ).filter(shared=True).order_by('-num_comments')

return qs
```

And now i get this error:

`KeyError at /recipe/popular/
<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7f90048f7470>`

I'm thinking there is a problem with the `mixin`.

I updated the view for get all values in `dispatch` function but i'm getting this error:

```
KeyError at /recipe/popular/
<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7f6ffebfa4e0>
```

Code [here](https://gist.github.com/SalahAdDin/105c03ec449cbe4cd5efde72fc18dba9).

I'm testing now other approach: 
I made a function for get this value since the model as a property:

```
@property
def get_comments_number(self):
    api_key = settings.DISQUS_API_KEY
    forum = settings.DISQUS_WEBSITE_SHORTNAME
    url = 'https://disqus.com/api/3.0/forums/listThreads.json?api_key={0}&forum={1}&thread:ident={2}'.format(
        api_key,
        forum,
        self.slug
    )
    raw = requests.get(url)
    thread = json.loads(raw.content)

    return thread['response'][0]['posts']
```

Whit this and a new field ordering will be more easy, but, how can i use this function for get the value and save in the database?
Which the best approach for this task?

Thank you.

Comment: show your model definition for `Recipe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i change my approach:

I created a new function property in my `recipe` model:

```
    @property
    def get_comments_number(self):
        api_key = settings.DISQUS_API_KEY
        forum = settings.DISQUS_WEBSITE_SHORTNAME
        url = 'https://disqus.com/api/3.0/forums/listThreads.json?api_key={0}&forum={1}&thread:ident={2}'.format(
            api_key,
            forum,
            self.slug
        )
        raw = requests.get(url)
        thread = json.loads(raw.content)

        return thread['response'][0]['posts']
```

After, i added a new field in the model for save the `comment's number` value.

Finally, i call that property in the `DetailView` in order to update the comment's number:

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

```
# TODO: maybe it is necessary create a task for update this in other cases
r = self.get_object()
r.comments = r.get_comments_number
r.save()

# check if the recipe is a private recipe if so through a 404 error
if r.shared == False and self.object.author != request.user:
    output = _("Recipe {0} is marked Private").format(self.get_object().slug)
    raise Http404(output)
else:
    return super(RecipeDetailView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And now i can filter by comment's number in the other view:

```
qs = qs.filter(shared=True).order_by('-comments')
```

And it's all.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to `.annotate()` and then ordery by this newly annotated attribute.

see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

Comment: Can i use a function for filter by slug in a dictionary and get the respective valua a a new annotate value?

Comment: No, i can't. I tested it and i'm getting this: `KeyError at /recipe/popular/
'slug'`

Comment: @SalahAdDin this call seems wrong `get_comments_number('slug')` because you have certain values of slugs there and not the constant key `slug`. Have a look on your code in `item = {thread['slug']: thread['posts']}`

Comment: If you have `slug` as field in `Recipe` model access it like these `F('slug')` and remember to import `from django.db.models import F`

Comment: For what?
I'm using extra now, but i'm getting other problem.

Comment: `KeyError at /recipe/popular/ F(slug)`